# A Specific Blog post to be assigned as the landing page of my wordpress blog

Tags: php, seo

Is it possible for a specific blog post (in wordpress) to be the landing page? For example my domain name is *www.overflowingstupidity.com* and I have this blog entitled post *"How to burn your house down in 3 easy steps"*

Whenever a user clicks or type in the url bar of the web browser my domain name, he/she will directed and landed on my blog post "How to burn your house down in 3 easy steps" instead of the default index.php file of my wordpress blog.

Is that possible? IF YES, can you point out to me how?

Comment: you can Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin for this purpose. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

Comment: Use `.htaccess` to redirect the homepage to your post.

Comment: Wordpress has direct settings for this. Did you check the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit the blog post and copy the contents.
2. Create a new page and paste that content. Make sure you use the same title.
3. Now Go to  http://www.overflowingstupidity.com/wp-admin/options-reading.php
4. Click **A static page** and choose your blog post.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create the page that you want to make your home page if it doesn't already exist. Log in to your Wordpress website, then click "Pages." Select the "New Page" button, then fill out the text fields that open, giving the page a name and permalink URL. Once the page has been created, edit it to contain the formatting and information you want for your website's home page. After the page has been created to your satisfaction, select the "Publish" button on the right-side of the text box.

Step 2: Select the "Administration" menu option from the left-side menu, then click "Settings," finally followed by the "Reading" link. You will see several more options; select "Front Page Displays." A list of all available pages will appear, including the home page that you created in Step 1.

Step 3: Select the page that you want to use as your home page, then click "Save." Open a new tab in your Web browser and navigate to your Wordpress website; you should see the static page as your home page instead of a list of the most recent posts that have been published. If the page doesn't meet your satisfaction, you can alter it in the tab with the control panel, then refresh the Web page to see the updated changes.